# Beat frequency when a bat flys towards a wall

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, acoustics, frequency, speed

A bat is flying towards a wall while emitting an ultrasound of frequency 25kHz. Emitted sound and the sound that bounces off a wall form a beat frequency 1.65kHz, that the bat detects. With what speed does the bat approach the wall? Speed of sound is 340m/s.

This is the full exercise. The answer is:

The bat detects the frequency:
$$
f=f_0\left(\frac{1+\frac{v}{c}}{1-\frac{v}{c}}\right)
$$
coming from invisible source that is approaching the bat with speed $v$ which is also the speed with which the bat is approaching the wall.

Beat frequency: 
$$
f_b=\frac{f-f_0}{2}
$$
and
$$
f=2\cdot f_b+f_0=f_0 \frac{1+ \frac{v}{c}}{1- \frac{v}{c}}
$$
From that we calculate:
$$
v=c \cdot \frac{f_b}{f_0+f_b}=20\,\text{m}/\text{s}
$$
I want to know why the beat frequency is $f_b=\frac{f-f_0}{2}$ and not $f_b=f-f_0$ . Any explanation would be much appreciated.

Comment: The OP seems to know the solution to the HW problem, but wants to understand something about concept of beat frequency. So, it’s not entirely HW-like

Comment: What is $c$? You should make it explicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The beat frequency, mathematically, is indeed $\frac{f - f_0}{2}$, as can easily be shown using the factor formula in trigonometry. However, the *perceived* beat frequency is twice of that, which is $f - f_0$. This is because the beat frequency modulates the amplitude of the sound wave. In one full cycle of $2\pi$, the amplitude goes both positive and negative, so we hear beats twice as often. See this image for a better visualization.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! How do you know when we're talking about $f_b=\frac{f-f_0}{2}$ and when $f_b=f-f_0$ ?

Comment: @luckha13 I think that would be up to interpretation. For example, if it is explicitly mentioned that beat frequency is heard, then it is probably $f - f_0$.

Comment: So basically I could solve the exercise in two ways? Could I use the other equation as well, even though the result wouldn't be the same?

Comment: what you have implied but not emphasized is that the *beat frequency* is not *in* the signal but rather is determined and created by your detector, here the ear. We call beats the *detected* fluctuating amplitude peaks of the two tones. These peaks are not in the signal, rather, if this was an electric circuit, they are formed by a diode and a low pass filter to smooth the rectified fluctuations of the envelope.

Answer (score 0):

It's purely trigonometric. A pair of sound wave interference can be modeled as:
$$ \cos(\omega_1\,t)+\cos(\omega_2\,t) = 2\,\cos\left(\frac{\omega_1+\omega_2}{2}\,t\right)\cos\left(\frac{\omega_1-\omega_2}{2}\,t\right)
$$
In right side of equation first frequency term is *modulation* angular frequency and second term is *beat* frequency.

Comment: I understood that, i don't fully understand when to use $f_b=\frac{f-f_0}{2}$ and when $f_b=f-f_0$ . Any chance to explain that a bit more? Please?

Comment: It may depend on sound detector characteristics, bat has sensitive ears, i.e. can hear and perceive low frequencies as audible tones, so it has $\frac 12 \omega$ of human audible beat frequency sensitivity.

Comment: thank you very much!